# Как в тег записать символ "

Tags: xml

В тегах храню нейкую информацию. К примеру

```
<SAMPLES sample="фирма Маша" />
```

Как сохранить в атрибуте именно вот так ---> фирма "Маша" (именно с ковычками)?

т.е. как бы так `<SAMPLES sample="фирма "Маша"" />`

Comment: &quot; или одинарные кавычки

Comment: Если использовать высокоуровневые API, наподобие `XDocument`/`XmlDocument`/`XmlWriter` и т. п., они сами экранируют символы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<SAMPLES sample="фирма &quot;Маша&quot;" />
```